# google cloud vision image properties

Tags: colors, google-api, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I am developing an application that uses the **Google vision API** and I have a question about the colors properties.

Is the color shown in the properties with the highest percentage is the dominant color? And how that works ?

Because the color with highest percentage is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

What is the feature you are using?

I suggest you provide a sample image, the sample request and the responses you get so we know more about how to improve.